# pysnmp How to use varBinds content of an incoming trap to forward a new trap?

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am writing a code to receive SNMP v2c traps, store them in a DB, and then forward the trap to another IP. I would like to confirm whether I may use the varBinds variable associated to the incoming trap, update its content, and use it as the info to populate the outgoing trap. Is it possible doing this just with pysnmp (not snmpfwd)?

I already tried to use the varBinds variable to build the second trap, however I get always an error when the script tries to send the second trap. Please find it below. This is part of the code I am using to receive and forward the trap. May anyone help? Thanks!

```
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore import *
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler, rfc1902, error

def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,         varBinds, cbCtx):
    execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext('rfc3412.receiveMessage:request')

    global mysqlEngine
    trapoid=''
    val=[]

    for x in varBinds:
        row = (rfc1902.ObjectType(rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(x[0]), x[1]).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)).prettyPrint().split(' = ')
        val.append(row[1]) <-- values to be added to the DB

    SendSNMPTrap('public','1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.0.4', varBinds)
    return

def SendSNMPTrap(community,trapoid, varBinds):

    global snmpEngine
    global mibViewController

    sendNotification(
        snmpEngine,
        CommunityData(community, mpModel=1),   
        UdpTransportTarget(('10.10.10.10', 162)),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(
            ObjectIdentity(trapoid) 
        ).addVarBinds(varBinds)
    )
```

'Malformed Object ID %s at %s: %s' % (value, self.**class**.**name**, sys.exc_info()[1])
;pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Malformed Object ID [('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.2.1.1', 100), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.2.1.7', 'text_tt0'), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.2.1.5', 'text_tt3'), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.5.2.0', 100), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.2.1.9', 'text_tt1'), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.2.1.10', 'text_tt2'), ('1.3.6.1.4.1.29172.22.2.3', 1)] at ObjectName: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to reuse the `varBinds` object for sending TRAPs. I think you should just unpack `varBinds` when passing them to [addVarBinds](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py#L1111).

That is:

```
 sendNotification(
    snmpEngine,
    CommunityData(community, mpModel=1),   
    UdpTransportTarget(('10.10.10.10', 162)),
    ContextData(),
    'trap',
    NotificationType(
        ObjectIdentity(trapoid) 
    ).addVarBinds(*varBinds)
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, I will test it and will update the thread. Thanks!